# How to override Object.ToString() method with a Extension Method?

Tags: c#, .net

The [object.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) method is used to convert any object to a string of readable text. But if the object is null it throws an `NullReferenceError`. So I want to override this `ToString()` method with an Extension Method like:

```
public static class StringExt
{
    public string ToString(this object str)
    {           
        if (str == null)
            return System.Convert.ToString(str);

        return str.ToString();
    }
}
```

But it seems like this never overrides the `ToString()` of the `Object` class.

```
Myclass cls;
//doing something on the other hand. 

cls.ToString();
```

Here `cls.ToString()` always uses the `Object.ToString()` method. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is the problem not that you will always be trying to dereference a null object and therefore will always throw an exception?

It looks like you're trying to solve the unsolvable...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Extension methods deliberately cannot supplant instance methods.

You need to use a different name.

Comment: I am not in the favor of different name as that can be easily missed. is ther any other way to override the implemantation for any kind of object.

Comment: @Jodha: You could rewrite IL.